# Strategy for assigning cores to threads (CPU Isolation) for HFT application

Tags: multithreading, performance, linux-kernel, cpu-cache, hft

We are developing a Java based HFT application which requires a tick-to-trade performance less than 10 micro-sec. Details below:

Number of cores : 6

No of application threads : 5

**Threads' functions & utilization**

- Thread 1-3 - capture exchange ticks (3-4% cpu utilization)
- Thread 4   - check trade conditions based on simple arithmetic rules (100% cpu utilization - due to busy spin)
- Thread 5   - checksum generation, int, double to byte conversion, send orders, etc (100% cpu utilization - due to busy spin)

**Question :**

We believe CPU isolation (assign threads exclusively to cores)  would reduce context switches and cache misses. Currently, we have assigned first 3 threads to 3 different cores. What is the best strategy to assign threads to cores in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of advantages and disadvantages of such approach you can find in Rober Love article on Linux Journal:CPU Affinity.

- Data access must be isolated on the same cpu.
- Also you should carefully deal with interrupts.
  More information you can find on lwn.net CPU isolation extensions.

Did you isolated cpu on kernel load steps or later?
I not familiar with JVM but what do you think about interaction JVM with cpu isolation approach?